# converting input in textfield to intigers javaFx

Tags: java, javafx

So I am trying to convert the input from a textField using the try and catch method but my code always just goes to the exception even if I input a value that can be converted.

```
    public int enterButton() throws Exception {
        inputLocation.setText("your location is: " + inputLocation.getText());
        
        int location = 49;
        String input = inputLocation.getText();
        try {
            location = Integer.parseInt(input);
            inputLocation.setText("your location is: " + location);
            
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            inputLocation.setText("Not a valid location!");
            error.setText("setting location as 49");
        }
        
        return location;
    }
```

what might be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger or other output to see exactly the contents of `input`?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int enterButton() throws Exception {
  inputLocation.setText("your location is: " + inputLocation.getText()); // <---
        
  String input = inputLocation.getText();
  try {
    location = Integer.parseInt(input);
  } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    ...
  }
  return location;
}
```

This logic will always make the content unparseable.

If the contents of location is `123`, the marked line will replace it with `your location is: 123`. After that, you will get that string into `input` and it will never parse because it contains the characters `your location is:`.

Don't do this -- either use a label in front of the field, or update a different field. Or at least, don't update the field before getting its text and trying to parse it.